# Error code 0x84B10001 при установке SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

При завершении установки вылазиет это окно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ошибка сообщает что об неверных символах в пути. Вы меняете путь установки или по умолчанию?

Comment: @Tivyram по умолчанию,пробовал и слэши менять в пути,не помогло.

Comment: А пользователь у вас на латинице или кириллице?

Comment: @Tivyram присутствет слово "ПК"

Comment: Вот в этом может и есть косяк

Comment: @Tivyram понял,спасибо. Напишите в виде ответа) чтобы поставить галочку)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка сообщает что об неверных символах в пути. Ошибка может исходить имени пользователя.